# Is there a way to combine multiple almost-same functions?

Tags: c++, function

Hardware stuff,
Interrupts need `void(*)()` - static function

So if I want interrupt to call members of specific object `T t`, I have to create some `T* t_star` for static function `void foo(){ t_star->whatever;}`to refer to.
If I want several interrupts, I have to have several such pairs of function-global_pointer

```cpp
T* t_star_1;
void foo_1() {t_star_1->whatever;}
T* t_star_2;
void foo_2(){t_star_2->whatever;}
...
```

As you can see, this causes code bloat of pretty much same thing
Now, combining `T*` is obvious - `T* Array[5]`

How do I do the same for functions? They differ only in a single array index now... Is there a way to not write each and one of them?

Comment: Often in this scenario the callback function will be of type `void(*)(void *)` -- i.e. it will have a void-pointer argument, and the callback-setup API will allow you to specify a `void *` value that the calling code will pass to the callback function when it is called.  That would allow you to create just a single `void foo(void *)` function which would call `static_cast<T*>(arg)->whatever();`.  If there's no mechanism for passing an argument, OTOH, you may be out of luck.  :(

Comment: @Oblivion oops... yeah, they're functions. But I don't think that "data member that is being used" would change anything.

Comment: Probably you could just use lambdas which are convertible to pure functions if they don't capture local variables `void(*callback)() = []{ t->foo(); };` or directly `register_callback([]{ t->foo(); });`

Comment: @NooneAtAll you may use std::mem_fn, I don't see much of a difference though.

Comment: Use preprocessor macros to generate those.

Comment: Move logic that is common to all the functions, to a separate function that can accept an argument.    That allows moving common code out of your set of interrupt functions (by providing the right parameter needed by the common function) quite easily.     It doesn't remove the need to write each interrupt function, but does simplify what they do.       Without more information (e.g. how the interrupts and data structures are set up, etc) it's not possible to give specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

> They [functions] differ only in a single array index now...

Sounds like what templates are designed to handle.

```
template <unsigned Index>
void foo()
{
    Array[Index]->whatever;
}
```

Your callbacks would then be `foo<0>`, `foo<1>`, etc. (It is strange that these callbacks take no parameters, though. In my experience, this sort of API often allows a `void*` parameter to pass data to the callback so that you do not have to resort to global variables.)

Here is another possibility, depending on how you planned to populate your array. This assumes you could initialize `Array[i]` to the return value of `get_data(i)`. This has the benefit of not requiring global variables.

```
template <unsigned Index>
void foo()
{
    static T * data = get_data(Index);
    data->whatever;
}
```